# Finding an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to query all records that are not already in an associated group.  So I have four models I'm working with including a `has_many through` association:

- `Account` which `has_one :credential` and `has_many :user_places`
- `Credential` which `belongs_to :account`
- `UserPlace` which `belongs_to :account` and `belongs_to :place`
- `Place` which `has_many :user_places` and `has_many :accounts, through: :user_places`

I'm trying to query `Credentials` that are not in the current place. It's been a while since I've worked with Rails and I'm getting caught up on the logic without writing a bunch of raw SQL.

So far I have something like:
`Credential.where('name LIKE ?', '%query%').joins(account: :user_place)`.
If I wrote out what I need with psudo code I think it would look like:

`Credential.where('name LIKE ?', '%query%').joins(account:  :user_place).where.not(account_id == UserPlace.account_id)`

Comment: Why are you having a where query with LIKE ?? Some information is missing here.

Comment: To look for a users with a `name` that matches a search query, I just don't want to show users that are already in the place.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to query on join tables in rails you can try like this below.

```
Credential.where('name LIKE ?', '%query%').joins(account: :user_place).where.not(user_places: {account_id: account_id})
```

i assume `UserPlace` table name in db is `user_places` otherwise you need to chage it.

Edit1:

Above query was for the pseudo code you mentioned. If you only want `Credential` records that have no relation with any `Place` then this should work for you:

`Credential.left_joins(account: :user_places).where(user_places: { id: nil }).where('name LIKE ?', '%query%')`

Comment: hmm, so something like this is ONLY returning records if the user is already in the place, `Credential.where('email LIKE ?', '%bob%').joins(account: :user_places).where.not(user_places: {place_id: 4})`.  If the user is not associated with the place via `user_place` they are not found.  This is the opposite of what I want, but I feel like it's on the right track.

Comment: edited the answer, hope it will help